# How do I resolve this mongod error code?

Tags: mongodb

I am about to start an API project and I have not used Mongodb in quite a while and do not use it everyday, so the context switching it killing me right now because I have used mongod successfully and now cannot remember how to get it up and running.

I tried by simply going to my command line and typing mongod but I get this error:

```
2016-12-26T11:16:13.285-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=41005 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=DCortes-MacBook-Pro-3.local
2016-12-26T11:16:13.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v3.4.0
2016-12-26T11:16:13.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: f4240c60f005be757399042dc12f6addbc3170c1
2016-12-26T11:16:13.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.2j  26 Sep 2016
2016-12-26T11:16:13.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2016-12-26T11:16:13.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2016-12-26T11:16:13.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2016-12-26T11:16:13.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2016-12-26T11:16:13.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2016-12-26T11:16:13.286-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2016-12-26T11:16:13.288-0500 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
2016-12-26T11:16:13.288-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2016-12-26T11:16:13.288-0500 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to flush diaglog...
2016-12-26T11:16:13.288-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2016-12-26T11:16:13.288-0500 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

and I have not been able to identify where in my directory is the error logs. Also, I have perused through Stack Overflow for similar posts but none of them spoke to what exactly is this error I am getting and how to fix it.

Comment: The error message says you tried to write to a read-only directory. Can you explain which part of that message is confusing to you?

Comment: the user is root,  ldco2016@DCortes-MacBook-Pro-3 ~ $ ls -ld /data/db                                                                                                                   [ruby-2.2.1]
drwxr-xr-x  29 root  wheel  986 Nov 11 00:15 /data/db and it is read-write-executable, so I guess there is the confusion.